# Messenger 2011: "Edit name" and "Edit profile" are grayed out

Tags: windows-live-messenger

[image]

Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your profile might not be provisioned or may be disabled for some reason. Try logging into profile.live.com and choosing your privacy settings and whatnot. Once you've done that, try logging out completely from Messenger, close, reopen, login.